# How can I write a tensor in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, tensors

My project is about tensors and I must write the program in MATLAB.
How can I write a tensor in MATLAB?
Is there anybody to help me?
Can you explain me what is the code for import a tensor?
thanks for your attention

Comment: This is the Math Stackexchange, I think you are not right here, is there a matlab stackexchange ?

Comment: but I see somebody ask their questions about Matlab or Mathematica right here.

Comment: Questions about Mathematica will be emigrated to the Mathematica Stackexchange. Just because you see something happens here, it doesn't mean it is intentional, else there wouldn't be that many duplicates etc. If there is enough interest you could join in the matlab stackexchange over here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38040/matlab ,

Comment: Nope there isn't a matlab stackexchange. People are working on it. In the meantime, people do ask MATLAB questions here all the time and they get answered.

Comment: For reference; MATLAB questions are asked (and solved) regularly on https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, there is a [tensor toolbox](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/TensorToolbox/index-2.5.html) for MATLAB managed by Sandia National Labs. The toolbox is free, open for anyone to download and use (with certain restrictions in the license of course). And there are some nice manuals with it as well.